# Selenium is not finding neccessary element on the page while working on vps server

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, vps, aiogram

I have the selenium parser, which clearly works on my own computer with no exceptions. However when im trying run it on my vps server i got the NoSuchElementException. Here is my code and the text of the problem:

> ```
> def csgo_registration():
>
>     options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
>     # options.add_argument("--headless")
>     options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
>     options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
>     options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
>     options.add_argument(f"user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "
>                          f"AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
>     driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
>
>     driver.get("https://lis-skins.ru/market/csgo/")
>
>     load_cookies(driver, "cookies.txt")
>
>     time.sleep(3)
>
>     driver.refresh()
>
>     time.sleep(3)
>
>     return driver
>
>
> def csgo_checker(driver, link, wait):
>
>     driver.get(link)
>     time.sleep(3)
>     try:
>         print(5)
>         print(5)
>         print(5)
>         no_skins_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="no-skins")
>         print("Nothing here")
>         return None
>
>     except NoSuchElementException:
>         desired_skin_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="market_item")
>         link_to_buy = desired_skin_elem.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="a").get_attribute("href")
>
>         good_naming = desired_skin_elem.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="name-inner").text
>         good_price = desired_skin_elem.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="price").text.split("cls")[0][:-1]
>         good_float = desired_skin_elem.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="info-item")[-1].text
>
>         print(good_price)
>
>         driver.get(link_to_buy)
>
>         time.sleep(3)
>
>         buy_now_btn = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "buy-now-button")))
>
>         buy_now_btn.click()
>
>         time.sleep(2)
>
>         try:
>             buy_now_popup_btn = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,
>                                                                        "buy-now-popup-bottom-button")))
>             buy_now_popup_btn.click()
>             message = f"Куплено успешно!\nНазвание: {good_naming}\nЦена: {good_price}₽\nФлот: {good_float}"
>             return [message, link_to_buy]
>
>         except TimeoutException:
>
>             message = "Недостаточно средств!"
>             return [message, link_to_buy]
> ```

And some problems from vps:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:407> exception=NoSuchElementException()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 75, in csgo_checker
    no_skins_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="no-skins")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 740, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".no-skins"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=114.0.5735.198); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
#0 0x560f46c9d4e3 <unknown>
#1 0x560f469ccc76 <unknown>
#2 0x560f46a08c96 <unknown>
#3 0x560f46a08dc1 <unknown>
#4 0x560f46a427f4 <unknown>
#5 0x560f46a2803d <unknown>
#6 0x560f46a4030e <unknown>
#7 0x560f46a27de3 <unknown>
#8 0x560f469fd2dd <unknown>
#9 0x560f469fe34e <unknown>
#10 0x560f46c5d3e4 <unknown>
#11 0x560f46c613d7 <unknown>
#12 0x560f46c6bb20 <unknown>
#13 0x560f46c62023 <unknown>
#14 0x560f46c301aa <unknown>
#15 0x560f46c866b8 <unknown>
#16 0x560f46c86847 <unknown>
#17 0x560f46c96243 <unknown>
#18 0x7f3d468bb609 start_thread


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "main.py", line 132, in send_welcome
    answer = csgo_checker(driver, link, wait)
  File "main.py", line 80, in csgo_checker
    desired_skin_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="market_item")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 740, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".market_item"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=114.0.5735.198); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
#0 0x560f46c9d4e3 <unknown>
#1 0x560f469ccc76 <unknown>
#2 0x560f46a08c96 <unknown>
#3 0x560f46a08dc1 <unknown>
#4 0x560f46a427f4 <unknown>
#5 0x560f46a2803d <unknown>
#6 0x560f46a4030e <unknown>
#7 0x560f46a27de3 <unknown>
#8 0x560f469fd2dd <unknown>
#9 0x560f469fe34e <unknown>
#10 0x560f46c5d3e4 <unknown>
#11 0x560f46c613d7 <unknown>
#12 0x560f46c6bb20 <unknown>
#13 0x560f46c62023 <unknown>
#14 0x560f46c301aa <unknown>
#15 0x560f46c866b8 <unknown>
#16 0x560f46c86847 <unknown>
#17 0x560f46c96243 <unknown>
#18 0x7f3d468bb609 start_thread
```

So if you know how to fix it or how to make python script with selenium works on vps server - I'm waiting for your help. Any interesting information is expected

Comment: Simply `print(drive.page_source)` right before `no_skins_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="no-skins")`

Comment: i actually tried it and get almost empty html, so i thought about cloudflare, however when i run it locally even with headless option it's working(